# How to change if-else statement to switch case statement in java

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

My question is how to change if-else statement to switch case statement, I've done some work and it contain error in netbean:

```
if(result.length <= 2){
            if ((result[0].equals("UC"))||(result[0].equals("uc"))){
                fix = "UC";
            }
            else if ((result[0].equals("LC"))||(result[0].equals("lc"))){
                fix = "LC";
            }
            else
                fix = "error";  
        }else
            fix = "length";
```

Comment: if you have java7+, you need to switch based on Strings and fall through cases "UC" and "uc" (and "lc" and "LC"), else can be the default case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution:

```
switch (Boolean.toString(result.length <= 2)) {
    case "true":
        switch (result[0]) {
            case "UC":
            case "uc":
                fix = "UC";
                break;
            case "LC":
            case "lc":
                fix = "LC";
                break;
            default:
                fix = "error";
        }
        break;
    default:
        fix = "length";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
switch (result[0]) {
    case "UC":
    case "uc":
        fix = "UC";
        break;
    case "LC":
    case "lc":
        fix = "LC";
        break;
    default:
        fix = "error";
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the default case, `fix="length";`.

Comment: @AntonH thanks for pointing .. I have updated my answer. I wanna make little correcttion that in default op use `fix = "error"` not `fix="length"`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(result.length <= 2){
        switch(result[0]){
                      case "UC":
                      case "uc":
                         fix = "UC";
                         break;
                      case "LC":
                      case "lc":
                         fix = "LC";
                         break;
                      default:
                         fix = "error";
                         break;
           }
      }
      else
        fix = "length";
```

Comment: same, also work for me...thanks dude...i'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
 if(result.length <= 2)
    {
        switch(result[0])
        {
            case "UC":
                fix = "UC";
                break;
            case "uc":
                fix = "uc";
                break;
            case "UC":
                 fix = "LC";
                 break;
            case "uc":
                 fix = "lc";
                 break;
            default:
                  fix = "error";
       }
 }
 else
 {
     fix = "length";
 }
```